# How to apply table header sorting to divs by an individual list element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a series of `<div>`s dynamically from an external query. Using Javascript a `<div>` is created and populated with separate list elements. The structure is something like:

```
<div class="container" id="1">
    <li class="date"> </li>
    <li class="name"> </li>
<div>
```

The search boxes run a jQuery livefilter on keyUp that hides `<div>`s that dont match the search.

I then want to be able to sort the visible divs by clicking on table headers that address individual `<li>` elements in the `<div>` (date, name, etc). I've tried using tablesorter and putting each `<li>` in a `<td>` but the table head ends up below the body and does not function.

**How can I apply sorting only to the currently visible list element but sort the entire div?**

[image: Diagram of table]

[JSFiddle of live filter with non operational header.](http://jsfiddle.net/F4BPG/)

Comment: Just a side not, an ID can't start with a number..... :O

Comment: @JamieHutber ...unless HTML5 document...

Comment: @JamieHutber ok, they aren't doing anything at the moment but I imagine I'll need them to function to sort the divs. I'll change them now.

Comment: LI elements do not belong in DIVs, they have to be inside a list element of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever, you encounter this kind of situation where you have to render something based on data changes, please consider decoupling between data and view layer. Because your view have to change as per data changes. You can implement this kind of logic on your own or you can use framework like Angular.js, Backbone.js, Ember.js etc. which tries to solve this kind of problem. Well in your case there are several ways to solve your problem but like I said earlier decoupling would be better (I think). You can do something like

Modified HTML (for easy data extraction). You can keep your original HTML but logic to pull data have to be changed.

```
Sort data by:
<a href="#">Date</a>&nbsp;<a href="#">Name</a>
<br />
<br />
<form id="live-search" action="" class="styled" method="post">
<fieldset>
    <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="Date" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter2" value="Name" />
    <br /> <span id="filter-count"></span>

</fieldset>
</form>
<ul class="records2" id="records">
<div data-record='{"year": "2012","name":"Joe"}'>
    <li>2012</li>
    <li>Joe</li>     
</div>
<br />
<div data-record='{"year": "2013","name":"Dave"}'>
    <li>2013</li>
    <li>Dave</li>

</div>
<br />
<div data-record='{"year":"2013","name":"Adam Brown"}'>
    <li>2013</li>
    <li>Adam Brown</li>  
</div>
```

```
function sortArray(arr, prop, asc) 
{
    arr = arr.sort(function(a, b) 
    {
        if (asc)
        {
            return (a[prop] > b[prop]);
        }
        else 
        {
            return (b[prop] > a[prop]);
        }
    });
    return arr;
}

$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var recordDiv = $('#records'), dataDivs = $('#records div'), data = [], sortLink = $('a');
    for (var i = 0, len = dataDivs.length; i < len; i++) 
    {
        var t = $(dataDivs[i]).attr('data-record');
        t = $.parseJSON(t);
        data.push(t);
    }
    sortLink.click(function()
    {
        var sortBy = this.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
        data = sortArray(data, sortBy, true);
        //Now render the element inside #record DIV as per sorted data
        return false;
    });
});
```

Let us know how it goes. :)